# Subquery a Cast Function

Tags: sql-server, casting, subquery

I have the following code which I'm using to transpose some data (see below); however, when running the code I received a 'Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for sum operator' error, which I believe is due to the fact the [RESULT_DT_TM] column has both date and time values. With the help from the outstanding contributors, I made what turns out to be a very simple code that removes the date from the [RESULT_DT_TM]:

```
select cast([RESULT_DT_TM] as time (0)) as [result_dt]
 from ED_Vitals_Import_Master
```

I would like to include this code within the main query so I have use the new [result_dt] variable but am having trouble embedding it. Is it possible to do what I am seeking?

```
Select *
From  (
    Select a.[PT_FIN]
          ,B.*
     From  (Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By PT_FIN Order by [RESULT_DT_TM]) From ED_Vitals_Import_Master ) A
     Cross Apply (values (concat('Time' ,RN),[RESULT_DT_TM])
                        ,(concat('Weight'   ,RN),[WEIGHT_RESULT])
                        ,(concat('SysBp'   ,RN),[SYSBP_RESULT])
                        ,(concat('DiaBP',RN),[DIABP_RESULT])
                        ,(concat('Temp' ,RN),[TEMPERATURE_RESULT])
                        ,(concat('Oxy'  ,RN),[OXYGEN_SAT_RESULT])
                        ,(concat('Fio'  ,Rn),[FIO2_RESULT])
                 ) B(Item,Value)
   ) src
 Pivot (sum(Value) for Item in  ([RESULT_DT_TM1],[Weight1],[Sysbp1],[DiaBP1], [Temp1], [Oxy1], [Fio1]
                            ,[RESULT_DT_TM2],[Weight2],[Sysbp2],[DiaBP2], [Temp2], [Oxy2], [Fio2]
                            ,[RESULT_DT_TM3],[Weight3],[Sysbp3],[DiaBP3], [Temp3], [Oxy3], [Fio3]
                            ,[RESULT_DT_TM4],[Weight4],[Sysbp4],[DiaBP4], [Temp4], [Oxy4], [Fio4]
                            ) ) pvt
```

Comment: This is one drawback of PIVOT vs. Conditional Aggregation.   PIVOT is expecting consistent datatypes.   As you know by now, you can't aggregate a datetime,  You can however convert the time into seconds from midnight

Comment: Failed to ask.  What does RESULT_DT_TM represent ?

Comment: Many thanks again, John. RESULT_DT_TM represents a column which contains both the date and time subject was admitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are mixing datatypes... perhaps a conditional aggregation would be more useful.

**Example**

```
Select a.[PT_FIN]
      ,[RESULT_DT_TM1] = max(case when RN=1 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)
      ,[Weight1]       = max(case when RN=1 then [Weight] end)
      ,[Sysbp1]        = max(case when RN=1 then [Sysbp] end)
      ,[DiaBP1]        = max(case when RN=1 then [DiaBP] end)
      ,[Temp1]         = max(case when RN=1 then [Temp] end)
      ,[Oxy1]          = max(case when RN=1 then [Oxy] end)
      ,[Fio1]          = max(case when RN=1 then [Fio] end)
      ,[RESULT_DT_TM2] = max(case when RN=2 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)
      ,[Weight2]       = max(case when RN=2 then [Weight] end)
      ,[Sysbp2]        = max(case when RN=2 then [Sysbp] end)
      ,[DiaBP2]        = max(case when RN=2 then [DiaBP] end)
      ,[Temp2]         = max(case when RN=2 then [Temp] end)
      ,[Oxy2]          = max(case when RN=2 then [Oxy] end)
      ,[Fio2]          = max(case when RN=2 then [Fio] end)
      --- Extend the Groups Here ---
 From  (Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By PT_FIN Order by [RESULT_DT_TM]) From ED_Vitals_Import_Master ) A
 Group By a.[PT_FIN]
```

Comment: Thanks John, I'll give those code a try. When you comment -Extend the Groups Here- are you you commenting on what the code is performing or action I should take in writing addition code?

Comment: Hi John, this code works amazing! Just trying to work my head around how it works!   Using the "[RESULT_DT_TM1] = max(case when RN=1 then [RESULT_DT_TM] end)" line as an example. What are the max function and RN=1 instructing the query to perform? Thanks!

Comment: @Greg If you run just the sub-query  Select *,RN=...   You will see how the RN comes into play.  Then it is a small matter for the conditional aggregation which groups by PT_FN.   You could use min() of even sum() on the non-date columns,